# send data to a new page and include it in the index-page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send data from a form to a new page that handles the result from the first page.
however, if I use

```
<form action = 'new_page.php' method = 'post'>
```

the browser swaps page to "new_page.php" and only shows that page. I'd like to display "new_page.php" in a separate div on the first page, with the results from the form.
I usually do this by writing my html at the top of the page and end with my php at the bottom. I start the php part with

```
 if(isset($_POST['var'])){ ... }
```

to only show the php part once the form has been used.

is this at all possible?
do I have to use ajax, jquery or plain javascript to fix this?
is there any other, relative easy, way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be using ajax to accomplish such a task , look at jquery `.post()` , `.get()` and `$.ajax()` .

```
$.post( "new_page.php", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: will look into that!
does this mean I can run the scripts with out reloading the page?

Comment: yeah , ajax is simply that .. you can send (post) data without reloading the page , or get data .

Comment: I've managed to use $.ajax() now, but the data that is being returned is in JSON. I know PHP can decode this using json_decode(), but I can't figure out how decode it since jQuery prints it straight to the div. can I somehow save the returned data in a variable and use that variable with php(to use json_decode())?

Comment: what do you want to do with the data ?!

Comment: simply display the returned data. I'm sending data to a script to do some calculations and I wan't to display them properly once they're returned. what I'm being returned right now is `{"returned_val":"test"}`

Comment: then just use `data.returned_val` this will return test

Comment: I'd like to format the text, too. bold, italic, adding some text before and after each returned value. I can't get `data.returned_val` to work.`success: function(data{$("#result").html(data);}` is working, but when I replace `.html(data)` with `.html(data.returned_val)` I get "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the HTML content of your 'new_page.php' inside the if(isset($_POST['var'])){...}

A simple way to do it would be..

```
if(isset($_POST['var']))
{
    echo<<<_END          //used for large HTML content
        <div id="myID">
            <span> MY HTML CONTENT </span>
        </div>
_END;          //be sure to use this withiut any white space before it
}
```

OR for one line HTML

```
if(isset($_POST['var']))
{
    echo "<div id='myID'>
            <span> MY HTML CONTENT </span>
        </div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In just javascript not jquery (demo):

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['test']))
{
    die($_POST['test']);
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc($test)
    {
    var xmlhttp;

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {

      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("testwindow").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
      }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("test=" + $test);


    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
loadXMLDoc("some text to return to page");
</script>
<div id="testwindow"></div>
</body>
</html>
```